# To get weekly record with subtotal for date range spanning over two years in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

As per the requirement i need to generate weekly report for given period. The below query works fine if the period is same year , but same fails if the year spans over two years . Because the Start week date of current year begins from previous year , which cause issue in the ordering of record.

Current Output

```
WEEK    DAY    FCB_ID     QUANTITY_ORDERS
1   12/29/2014  1935    1
1   12/30/2014  1935    1
1   12/31/2014  1935    1
1   1/1/2015    1935    1
1   1/2/2015    1935    1
1   1/3/2015    1935    1
1   1/4/2015    1935    1
1                1      7
2   1/5/2015    1935    1
2   1/6/2015    1935    1
2   1/7/2015    1935    1
2   1/8/2015    1935    1
2   1/9/2015    1935    1
2   1/10/2015   1935    1
2   1/11/2015   1935    1
2                  1    7
3   1/12/2015   1935    1
3   1/13/2015   1935    2
3   1/14/2015   1935    3
3   1/15/2015   1935    3
3                1      9
51  12/15/2014  1935    1
51  12/16/2014  1935    1
51  12/17/2014  1935    1
51  12/18/2014  1935    1
51  12/19/2014  1935    1
51  12/20/2014  1935    1
51  12/21/2014  1935    1
51               1      7
52  12/22/2014  1935    1
52  12/23/2014  1935    1
52  12/24/2014  1935    1
52  12/25/2014  1935    1
52  12/26/2014  1935    1
52  12/27/2014  1935    1
52  12/28/2014  1935    1
52              1       37
```

**Expected Result**
Week number in desc for previous year and asc for current year

```
51  12/15/2014  1935    1
51  12/16/2014  1935    1
51  12/17/2014  1935    1
51  12/18/2014  1935    1
51  12/19/2014  1935    1
51  12/20/2014  1935    1
51  12/21/2014  1935    1
51               1      7
52  12/22/2014  1935    1
52  12/23/2014  1935    1
52  12/24/2014  1935    1
52  12/25/2014  1935    1
52  12/26/2014  1935    1
52  12/27/2014  1935    1
52  12/28/2014  1935    1
1   12/29/2014  1935    1
1   12/30/2014  1935    1
1   12/31/2014  1935    1
1   1/1/2015    1935    1
1   1/2/2015    1935    1
1   1/3/2015    1935    1
1   1/4/2015    1935    1
1                1      7
2   1/5/2015    1935    1
2   1/6/2015    1935    1
2   1/7/2015    1935    1
2   1/8/2015    1935    1
2   1/9/2015    1935    1
2   1/10/2015   1935    1
2   1/11/2015   1935    1
2                  1    7
3   1/12/2015   1935    1
3   1/13/2015   1935    2
3   1/14/2015   1935    3
3   1/15/2015   1935    3
3                1      9
3                1      37
```

**Query details**

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT to_char(to_date(day),'IW') as Week, day as Day, NVL(fcb_id,1) as FCB_ID,sum(Quantity_Orders)Quantity_Orders

FROM
(
SELECT 
day, fcb_id, mo_number, count(DISTINCT mo_number) Quantity_Orders

FROM report_table
WHERE fcb_id = '1111'  
AND day >=  TRUNC(to_date('12/15/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY'))  --[SD]
AND day <=  TRUNC(to_date('1/15/2015', 'MM/DD/YYYY'))  --[ED]
GROUP BY day, fcb_id, mo_number
ORDER BY fcb_id, day, mo_number
)
GROUP BY ROLLUP(to_char(to_date(DAY),'IW'), day, fcb_id)
ORDER BY to_char(to_date(DAY),'IW'), day, fcb_id
)
WHERE  (FCB_ID = 1 AND DAY IS NULL) OR (FCB_ID != 1); -- this condition is used to remove extra row generated after each day due to DAY field in Rollup function
```

Comment: You have to add year to the GROUP BY.

Comment: Use `to_char(to_date(day),'IYYYYIW')` instead.

Comment: the use of `to_date(day)` is a bug. Either the day column is already in DATE format, and thus you're relying on an extra implicit conversion being done using the default nls_date_format settings to truncate it to a day or you've not specified the format mask explicitly and are again relying on the default nls_date_format settings. If those should happen to change, then bingo! Errors...

Answer (score 0):

**Note: edited after ravish comment.**

If I understand it, the solution only affects the "order by" clause. You have to include the year (the iso year) in the order by.

But your query has one dangerous error. Oracle (and most RDBMS) only ensures the order of the most outer select (inner select order are not ensure).
And your outer query is:

```
SELECT * FROM (...) WHERE  (FCB_ID = 1 AND DAY IS NULL) OR (FCB_ID != 1)
```

It has not order clause. Both order clauses are in inner queries, so order is not ensured in all cases.

Usually, to avoid the error you must include the order by clause in the outer select (and inner "order by" are not needed), but in this case it can cause interferences with ROLLUP function.

So we are going to eliminate the external select, transforming external WHERE condition into internal HAVING condition (so ROLLUP and ORDER BY can see the same data).

And then the next problem is how to know the year in rollup subtotals.
We solve this adding the iso-year in the rollup first argument:

```
ROLLUP(to_char(to_date(DAY),'IYYYIW'), day, fcb_id)
```

and letting the SELECT clause to extract the week and remove the year (using SUBSTRING).

Including the year in ROLLUP does not affect the group and subtotal creation, it allows ORDER BY to know the year and finally the SELECT clause eliminates it.

Beware, do not use this:

```
SELECT to_char(to_date(day),'IW') as Week,...
```

because oracle will not recognize that to_char(to_date(day),'IW') is a group by expression. You must use SUBSTR over the first argument of ROLLUP.

```
SELECT SUBSTR(to_char(to_date(day),'IYYYIW'),5) as Week,...
```

So the final query is:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(to_char(to_date(day),'IYYYIW'),5) as Week, day as Day, NVL(fcb_id,1) as FCB_ID,sum(Quantity_Orders)Quantity_Orders

FROM
(
SELECT 
day, fcb_id, mo_number, count(DISTINCT mo_number) Quantity_Orders

FROM report_table
WHERE fcb_id = '1111'  
AND day >=  TRUNC(to_date('12/15/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY'))  --[SD]
AND day <=  TRUNC(to_date('1/15/2015', 'MM/DD/YYYY'))  --[ED]
GROUP BY day, fcb_id, mo_number
)
GROUP BY ROLLUP(to_char(to_date(DAY),'IYYYIW'), day, fcb_id)
HAVING  (NVL(fcb_id,1) = 1 AND DAY IS NULL) OR (NVL(fcb_id,1) != 1)
ORDER BY to_char(to_date(DAY),'IYYYIW'), day, fcb_id;
```

Comment: Hi all, thnx for the responses .
The suggested changes are not working because of sub total being null value , and this makes all the record with subtotal to come in last .
Could some one suggest alternative approach , for subtotal weekly data with maintaining the squence of older week in previous yr .

Comment: the query is working after giving year in iso format.

Comment: @Ravish While I was editing the answer with your first comment, your second comment arrives. So perhaps you do not need the answer now. I'm happy to know that you have solved the problem.